# Fragment cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

This is my first time using fragments (new to android dev) and I'm trying to set up a spinner.  At the moment I am quite confused about context and can't seem to solve this error:

```
Error:(52, 78) error: incompatible types: HotkeysFragment cannot be converted to Context
```

Here is the code its referring to:

HotkeysFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    Spinner hotkey_selector_spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hotkey_selector_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hotkey_selector_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hotkeys, container, false);
    rootView = rootViewB;
    return rootViewB;
}
```

The specific line is:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Imports:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: change `this` to `getActivity()`

Comment: Why is the code in `onCreate` if its Fragment? Look at the fragment lifecycle and to get context in fragment use `getActivity()`. `hotkey_selector_spinner ` will be null leading to NPE

Comment: So if it shouldnt be in onCreate then should it be in onCreateView?  At the moment the app is crashing, is this why?

Comment: @mtmeyer i would suggest look at the fragment documentation especially the lifecycle part

Comment: @Raghunandan So after some reading on the life cycle it seems using the `onActivityCreated` would be better. Is this correct?

Comment: @mtmeyer you can do it there. also getActivity() to be used after fragment is attached to the activity. you can use getActivity in onCreateView.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for your help, its all working now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Android docs on Fragments from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can
>   call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only
>   when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not
>   yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle,
>   getActivity() will return null.

So, in addition to changing `this` to `getActivity()`, I also suggest that you work with `getActivity()` in `onActivityCreated()` (since you also need the view to be inflated first)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    Spinner hotkey_selector_spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.hotkey_selector_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hotkey_selector_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting this: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference` which i assume means its still returning null

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account that you also need the view to be inflated when creating the adapter

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
        R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Access context in fragment by using `getActivity()`

Comment: @Holmes This is message is for ??

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` can not be converted into `Context`, an `Activity` can.

So you should change

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
        R.array.hotkey_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to access `context` inside any `Fragment` is by using the `getActivity()` method.

You can also get it directly from the `ViewGroup` inside `onCreateView`. If you go this way you won't get `null` as you could get from `getActivity()` (*as long as you instantiate it for an user interface view before*).

```
fragment_context = container.getContext();
```

Comment: the `container` can be null. It states this in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater%2C%20android.view.ViewGroup%2C%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: It will only return `null` if the fragment it's not instantiated for an user interface view, which makes no sense since you're using it for this reason.

Comment: You are right. Most of the times you will never see this method executed without a container. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout) say that the fragment "may still be created from its saved state" with a null `container`. I know this is an edge case, but it can still happen, making the code unnecessarily fragile. You never know how you might need to use this fragment in the future; the fragment system is full of bugs as it is, no need to have even more exposure.